# Inserting to specific row GoogleSpreadsheet - Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a code in Python which inserts data to Google Spreadsheet. How can I select the row which I want to insert data to? For example:
I have three variables: temperature, humidity, pressure and actual date and they need to be insterted to row from E1 to H1?

```
import time
import httplib2
# Do OAuth2 stuff to create credentials object
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
#from oauth2client.tools import tools
import math
import tools
import getopt
import sys
import string
import datetime


storage = Storage("creds.dat")
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    flags = tools.argparser.parse_args(args=[])
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets("client_secret.json", scope=["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"])
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
if credentials.access_token_expired:
    credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())

# Use it within old gdata
import gdata.spreadsheet.service
import gdata.service

client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService(
    additional_headers={'Authorization' : 'Bearer %s' % credentials.access_token})

#public example
spreadsheet_key = my_spreadsheet_key'
entry = client.GetSpreadsheetsFeed(spreadsheet_key)
print entry.title

temp=20
pressure = 1000
humidity = 40


#       # Prepare the dictionary to write

dict = {}
dict['datetime'] = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
dict['ctemp'] = str(temp)
dict['pressure'] = str(pressure)
dict['humidity'] = str(humidity)

rangeName = 'E1:H1'



#What should I write here?


#print dict
#entry = client.InsertRow(dict, spreadsheet_key, 'od6')
#if isinstance(entry, gdata.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetsList):
        #print "Insert row succeeded."
#else:
#       print "Insert row failed."
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout a library [pygsheets](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets), i wrote for google sheets api v4, using that the above can be achieved by

```
import pygsheets

gc = pygsheets.authorize()

# Open spreadsheet and then workseet
sh = gc.open('my new ssheet')
wks = sh.sheet1

# Update the range 
wks.update_cells(crange='E1:H1', [[temp,pressure,humidity]])
```

if you really want to use gdata , then checkout [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread)